# Call a method from a file and parse the file

Tags: python, class, constructor

I am doing something wrong.It should open the file using a constructor and will call a method `read_names_from_files()` that will parse the above file that counts each word. As an example in idle, I ran this program:

```
>>> import fish
>>> a = fish.Fishes("filename.txt")
>>> freqs = a.read_names_from_files()
>>> freqs
>>> {}
```

But it did not show the parsing content from dictionary.

```
class Fishes:
def __init__(self, fn):
    self.file1 = open(fn, 'r')
    self.freqs=self.read_names_from_files()

def read_names_from_files(self):
    freqs = {}
    for line in self.file1:
        for word in line.split():
            if word in freqs:
                freqs[word] += 1
            else:
                freqs[word] = 1
    return freqs
```

Comment: when i try to run it, it appears:Fishes instance has no attribute fish

Comment: The code in your question would not generate that error, so it must be from other code that creates and attempts to use the class. Please add that you your question (as well as your comment).

Comment: Why do you init file1 and then open the file again in read_names_from_files?

Comment: You will only get a useful answer if you show _actual_ code.  The code given in this question is full of typos (e.g. `Class` with a capital C, `freqs` vs. `self.freqs`, `slf` instead of `self`), and would result in lots of errors, but definitely not in the error you claim it results in.

Comment: The question is , the class must contain the constructor and it will open a file by taking it as an argument.it should  call a method read_names_from_files() that will parse the file and put it into the dictionary

Comment: @martineau, i tried to parse the file in the method read_names_from_files() and store in a dictionary and print it. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Sorry, your code had too many errors for me to discuss each one or to even figure out which one was the primary cause your problem.

```
class Fishes:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.file1 = open(fn, 'r')

    def read_names_from_files(self):
        freqs = {}
        for line in self.file1:
            for word in line.split():
                if word in freqs:
                    freqs[word] += 1
                else:
                    freqs[word] = 1
        return freqs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import fish  # assume this file is named "fish.py"
    a = fish.Fishes("fish.py")  # read it as test data
    freqs = a.read_names_from_files()
    assert freqs['for'] == 2  # raise exception if untrue
```

Comment: how to call the function read_names_from_files(self) by  def __init__(self, fn)? can i call it like: class Fishes:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.file1 = open(fn, 'r')
        self.read_names_from_files(self) 
so what will be the output format ? just same as before?

Comment: i tried the code like that:
class Fishes:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.file1 = open(fn, 'r')
        self.freqs=self.read_names_from_files()

    def read_names_from_files(self):
        freqs = {}
        for line in self.file1:
            for word in line.split():
                if word in freqs:
                    freqs[word] += 1
                else:
                    freqs[word] = 1
        return freqs

when i tried to run the code:
import fish
>>> a = fish.Fishes("x.txt")
>>> freqs= a.read_names_from_files()
>>> freqs
{}
which is empty dict

Comment: jack15: Your modifications call `read_names_from_files()` from `Fishes.__init__()` and assign the result to `self.freqs`. When you explicitly call it again via the `freqs = a.read_names_from_files()`, the file has already been read completely, so there are no more lines to be read which results in it returning an empty dict. Use `freqs = a.freqs` instead (or just refer to `a.freqs` directly as it will have values in it put there by your changes to `__init__()`). Why did you make the changes you did since what's in my answer works.